# JComponent wont show image

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, jcomponent, paintcomponent

Im a beginner programmer and Im trying to get this program to run. Everything compiles correctly although no images appear on the new Java screen for the JComponent. Pretty much what this program is suppose to do is take an input value and assign it to to the values of a bar chart for size. In the program I have to use an exterior paintcomponent class to run the original class as well as have a driver which is probably what is throwing me off.  Thanks in Advance!

```
public class BarChartTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      BarChartPaintComponent component = new BarChartPaintComponent();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the Values you wish to use (>0). Press -1 on an empty line to stop");
      Boolean flag = false;
      while(!flag)
      {
           double numbers = in.nextDouble();
           if(numbers == -1)
           flag = true;
           else if(numbers<-1)
           System.out.println("You have typed in invalid number");
           else
           component.add(numbers);
     }
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(300, 300);
      frame.setTitle("A Bar Graph");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(component);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class BarChart extends JComponent
{
private ArrayList<Double> list;
private double value;
private int i;

public BarChart()
{

    list = new ArrayList<Double>();
}


public void add(double value)
{
    list.add(i, value);
    i++;
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Double greatest = list.get(0);
    Double least;
    for(int j =1;j<=list.size();j++)
    {
        if(list.get(j)> greatest)
        greatest = list.get(j);
        else
        least = list.get(j);


    }

    for(int i = 0;i<=list.size();i++)
    {
        int x = 20;
        int width = 20;
        double barNumber = list.get(i);
        double size = barNumber;
        if(list.get(i) == greatest){
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,300,width,300));
        }
        else
        {
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
             g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,300,width, barNumber));
         }

        x +=20;

    }



}










}


public class BarChartPaintComponent extends BarChart
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g, double array){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    BarChart component= new BarChart();
    component.add(array);
    component.draw(g2);

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to programming! You have two loops that run through your list, with "for" statements like this: for(int j =1;j<=list.size();j++) and this: for(int i = 0;i<=list.size();i++). However, when your list has N elements, you need to use the numbers 0, 1, 2... N-1 to access them, not 0, 1, 2... N. So your loops should not test for "<=list.size()," they should both test for "< list.size()." This is a _very_ common mistake by new programmers (I made it many times, myself). Try that correction before you do more work on this program. Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot but that doesnt exactly answer my question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that the code intended do draw will never be called, since you are not implementing the paintComponent(Graphics g) method. So, replace your paintComponent for this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    this.draw(g2);
}
```

Then make the corrections suggested by Stevens.

Also, in the second for, you are initializing the variable x (int x = 20). This way, x will be 20 at every iteration of the loop. Do this before the for loop.

Comment: I think Alexandre has got it right, though I suspect your program probably threw an exception you didn't see because of the problems I found as well. An alternative to Alexandre's solution might be to simply change the name of your "draw" method to "paintComponent," since that will override the paintComponent method of the JComponent object that BarChart extends, and your "draw" method already does the cast from the Graphics parameter (g) to a Graphics2D object. I have upvoted Alexandre's answer because I think he's found your problem, but also because he approved my suggestion 8-).